# asp core project can't starting HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-core

I can't understand why this project don't start. It's logs don't give me normal explanation. I use asp core and have project version 1.0.1. I install .NET Core 1.1 Runtime & Hosting Bundle server because this latest version. I'm not be able to update project.

Logg :

```
   info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
          User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
          Executed DbCommand (120ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
          Executed DbCommand (106ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
          SELECT CASE
              WHEN EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a])
              THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
          END
    crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
          Unable to start Kestrel.
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.Start(Int32 count)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)<---


    Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.NativeMethods.uv_loop_size()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init(Libuv uv)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelThread.ThreadStart(Object parameter)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.Start(Int32 count)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
       at Messenger.Web.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

web config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
   <aspNetCore requestTimeout="02:00:00" 
     processPath="C:\Repository\publish\Messenger.Web.exe" 
     
     stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
     stdoutLogFile="C:\Repository\publish\logs\stdout" 
     forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 30c02729-bd76-4a5f-9ed8-07828eb9edb3-->
```

Comment: Have you ensured that database connection string is correct?

Comment: Yes, i have.  This is Azure database and i tested local that this work

Comment: How did you publish the application initially? `win-x86` or `win-x64`? What's the application pool setting right now for this application pool? 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: win-x86. I have had a problem with publish projest from win-64. Ok, i will try to start from x64. Thank you !

Comment: For future readers, this issue was reported on GitHub as well, https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/214 So you can read those threads to learn more background information.

Answer (score 0):

Your log is full of exceptions **System.BadImageFormatException**. I had the same issue when I tried to run my ASP.NET Core application on IIS. Apparently, there is processor type mismatch between the web application and the web server. I solved it by setting the "Target runtime" to "Portable" in the Publish settings in Visual Studio. You use a different web server, but this exception has always the same reason. You need to have all dll files in the same bitness, because the web server runs the application in-process.

Comment: You probably answered the wrong question. Mind you that this question is specific to ASP.NET Core 1.1, so "in-process" hosting was mission impossible then.

Comment: @LexLi I think you are wrong. The exception log shows that Kestrel web server is used in this case. According to my knowledge, Kestrel runs the web application always in-process.

Comment: Then you need to study the concepts again. "In-processing hosting" now refers to IIS HTTP Server, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2